# Software that can capture a 2D game world onto a big image

Tags: windows, images, mapping

I'm looking for some sort of software that I could use to create detailed maps of 2d games, since it's kind of a pain to manually take screenshots and put them all together.

It would work something like this: 
I would walk around in the 2D game world and as I do that the game world would be captured onto one big image, like a big, very detailed map. Like one you would get if you walked around and manually took screenshots and edited them together with some kind of image editing software.

I've tried searching for some kind of software that could do this but so far I haven't found any at all.

Answer (score 3):

One trick that you could use would be to:

1. Use screen recording software, (there are a number of free ones out there such as [Atomi](https://atomisystems.com/activepresenter/free-edition/), *or you can use ImageMagick with the import command and a delay but the syntax is convoluted*), to record the "Walk Through" to a video file.
2. Use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/), or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), to spit out still shots at a rate chosen so that you have a reasonable amount of overlap between them.
3. Use ImageMagick to trim each image to limit it to the active area of the screen, i.e. to remove any frame, etc.
4. Use [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) to order and stitch together then images into the one big one - unlike many panorama programs Hugin is very good at figuring out the order that images fit together.  If you have enough overlap, (which will take longer), you can even let it remove any sprites based on the fact that they do not occur in the same location over the background.

You might wish to do this in an iterative manner so as to speed things up - i.e. extract and trim 10 frames then combine them into a moderately big image - do the same with a group including at least one of those frames and 9 new, adjacent, frames.

Before starting this process make **sure** that you have ***lots*** of free disk space you will need it.

All of the software mentioned above is Free (gratis) and *with the exception of Atomi* is open source and cross platform.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use FFMPEG or ImageMagick, but I managed to use [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.org/) instead to export the video as an image sequence.

I'm still hoping to find a way to simplify the full process more but this certainly works.

Comment: @Sebastian - Good to hear. FFMPEG & ImageMagick take some learning because they are just so powerful but definitely the way to go when trying to automate because they are both scriptable.

Comment: +1 for Hugin. Found out about it a few months ago and has made image stitching much less of a hassle for me.